# Indexeddb with Node Webkit

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, node-webkit

I am very new to IndexedDB with Node WebKit, I have a database in my project which is required to store some information, due to continuous development now we have multiple databases in IndexedDB, does anyone knows how to delete all the created database from IndexedDB in one go?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: @john, thanks for the feedback. I will surely follow this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such API to drop all object stores, either you have iterate through all object store (which I think you don't want to do) or you can delete the database itself, as shown using below code:

```
            var dbDeleteRequest = window.indexedDB.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);
            dbDeleteRequest.onerror = function(event) {
                //Code
            };
            dbDeleteRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
                //Code
            };
```